# SalesForce delete Lead using Force.com toolkit for .NET

Tags: .net, salesforce, force.com

I am implementing adapter for SalesForce and I am facing strange problem upon deleting a lead.

I am using DeveloperForce.Force 1.3.2 - 
 Force.com Toolkit for .NET:
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET#forcecom-toolkit-for-net--
Install-Package DeveloperForce.Force

```
public void DeleteLead(DeleteRequest request)
{
    Task.Run(() => DeleteObject(request));
}

private async Task DeleteObject(DeleteRequest request)
{
    _client.DeleteAsync("Lead", "id").Wait(); //Option 1

    bool isDeleted = _client.DeleteAsync("Lead", "id").Result; //Option 2

    bool isDeleted_2 = await _client.DeleteAsync("Lead", "id"); //Option 3

    bool isDeleted_3 = await Task.Run(() => _client.DeleteAsync("Lead", "id")); //Option 4

    _client.DeleteAsync("Lead", "id").Wait(); //Option 5
}
```

The problem: No matter which Option 1/2/3/4/5 I am using the behavior is:
- the execution stops -> the debugger stops automatically -> I have to start the debugging again
- the lead is not deleted
- no exception is raised

Any ideas how to fix this?
Best regards,
Svet

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a sample record
Console.WriteLine("Creating test record.");
var lead = new Lead { Name = "Test Lead" };
var createLeadResponse = await client.CreateAsync(Lead.SObjectTypeName, lead);
lead.Id = createLeadResponse.Id;
if (lead.Id == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to create test record.");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Successfully created test record.");

Console.WriteLine("Deleting the record by ID.");
var deleted = await client.DeleteAsync(Lead.SObjectTypeName, lead.Id);
if (!deleted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the record by ID!");
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("Deleted the record by ID.");
```

I tested this code using DeveloperForce.Force 1.3.2 and it does work. **Option 3** seems to the accurate one. The way I tried it is:

1. Downloaded the "Simple Console Application" from [Force.com Toolkit for Net GitHub page](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/).
2. Complied the solution
3. Created a Connected App for OAuth and specified credentials in the App.config of the simple console application code.
4. Ran the code and inspected the flow.
5. Everything ran successfully

Please check & let me know if this works for you.